# Superfish IE7 z-index bug with Nivo slider or Photospace in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, superfish

I have a website with a superfish menu and I have two different plugins for slideshows, nivo slider in the main page: http://hermandaddelcalvario.org/wordpress/ and photospace in the gallery page: http://hermandaddelcalvario.org/wordpress/imagenes-3/

The problem comes with IE7, the dropdown falls behind the images on both pages. I searched a lot and everyone suggests that I do this:

```
/*gallery container*/
#content{
position:relative;
z-index: 1;
}

/*superfish container*/
#navwrap{
position:relative;
z-index: 2;
}
```

I did so but to no avail, is there something else I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is a bit lame, 3 secs after I asked the question I found my answer here: [Jquery Superfish problem in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889633/jquery-superfish-problem-in-ie7)

Using that script now it works but I still want to know what's wrong with the css here, I'd go for a css solution before this but I wanted to state that would solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue occurs in both IE 6 and 7 due to the way they create a stacking order. More details can be found here: http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/

In short - within your conditional IE stylesheets you will need to give your menus parent a z-index of higher value than your slideshow.

Comment: If you read my question that's exactly what I did but didn't work.

Comment: This is all the (pretty nasty) Javascript solution above is doing. It's simply giving all the div elements (why single out the humble divs =( ?) a specified z-index to force a stacking order.

Comment: +1 for this solution - I had this exact problem using nivo slider next to superfish and this css worked for me:  li.sfHover {z-index:1000;}